# How to convert desearilize boolean in MockMVC?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Hi I have a boolean variable in my class and I was trying to post this class in my spring boot testing.

However I encountered error as below:

```
2020-07-21 03:42:11.590  WARN 11660 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spbrResponse' on field 'isSuccess': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.spbrResponse.isSuccess,typeMismatch.isSuccess,typeMismatch.boolean,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spbrResponse.isSuccess,isSuccess]; arguments []; default message [isSuccess]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [null] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty boolean] for value 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type]]
```

The boolean field is called isSuccess and I already have getter and setter method:

```
public class SpbrResponse<T> {
    private boolean isSuccess;
    private T result;
    private String error;

    public void setIsSuccess(boolean isSuccess) {
        this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
    }    

    public boolean getIsSuccess() {
        return isSuccess;
    }
}
```

In unit testing I use ObjectMapper to convert object into JSON:

```
    ReportGenerationResponse response = new ReportGenerationResponse(1, 1, 1, 1, "xx", "yy", "zz");
    SpbrResponse<ReportGenerationResponse> wrappedResponse = new SpbrResponse<>(true, response, "");

    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/ReportComplete")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(wrappedResponse))
    )
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

I also tried to use

1. @JsonProperty
2. Rename setter method to setSuccess()

but all failed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: a `boolean` uses `setXXX` and `isXXX` not `setXXX` and `getXXX`. Now  a `Boolean` does use `getXXX` and `setXXX`. The first is a primitive boolean which is slightly different according to the Java Beans Specification then an object Boolean. So rename your `getIsSuccess` to `isIsSuccess`. The issue isn't your setter but your getter.

Comment: I tried setXXX and isXXX but error persists. :-(

Comment: Still the problem is your getter, as it doesn't send the actual value but rather `null` which comes from the mismatch not using `is` instead of `get`.

Comment: I tried different combinations of setXXX, getXXX, setIsXXX and getIsXXX. Unfortunately none is working....

Comment: you need a `setIsSuccess` and `isIsSuccess`. The latter looks weird due to the name of your property so using `isSuccess` won't work yuou need the double `is`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer would be using @JsonProperty annotation. I tried to use this at first but in a wrong way. Correct syntax would be:

```
public class SpbrResponse<T> {
    @JsonProperty("isSuccess")
    private boolean isSuccess;
    private T result;
    private String error;
}
```